# Search JavaScript Array for Count of All Items that Match a String Pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint-2013

I need to search a JavaScript Array for a count of all the items that match a string.  So for example, the array will contain these elements:

- ABC #1
- ABC #1
- ABC #1
- ABC #2
- ABC #3
- DEF #1
- DEF #2
- GHI #2

What I want to do is to search the Array for a string such as "ABC" and then get a count of the number of items that match that pattern. I'm pulling the data from SharePoint 2013 list using REST API.  Here is my relevant code so far:

```
var arrayPartySet = []; 

$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {

  var partySet = value.Party_x0020_Set;

  arrayPartySet.push(partySet); 
  //alert("arrayPartySet " + arrayPartySet);//For Testing

});
```

What I've tried in Javascript

`.find` - Only brings back the value of the first element in the array

`.includes` - Only tells me if the array contains the element

If anyone has seen this problem and knows how to resolve it, please provide guidance and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the $filter in REST API directly to get the items.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('customlist')/items?$filter=substringof('ABC',Party_x0020_Set)
```

To search the string array, we can use the code as below to achieve it.

```
var count = arrayPartySet.filter(function(item){ return item.includes("ABC"); }).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce`, and inside the callback, check whether the current item being iterated over `.includes` the needle you're searching for:

```js
const arr = [
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #2',
  'ABC #3',
  'DEF #1',
  'DEF #2',
  'GHI #2',
];
const count = arr.reduce((a, str) => a + str.includes('ABC'), 0);
console.log(count);
```

If you don't like `.reduce`, this is equivalent to the longer code of:

```js
const arr = [
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #2',
  'ABC #3',
  'DEF #1',
  'DEF #2',
  'GHI #2',
];
let count = 0;
for (const str of arr) {
  if (str.includes('ABC')) {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` to filter through which strings include ABC, then find the length of the array.

```js
var arr = [
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #1',
  'ABC #2',
  'ABC #3',
  'DEF #1',
  'DEF #2',
  'GHI #2',
];
var count = arr.filter(str => str.includes('ABC')).length;
console.log(count);
```